# Problem with Arduino Uno sending data to MATLAB

Tags: arduino, matlab

I am sending data from an Arduino Uno to MATLAB. Below is my Arduino and MATLAB code:

Arduino Code:

```cpp
const float sensorVoltage = A0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);     
}

void loop() {
  float inputVoltage2 = analogRead(sensorVoltage);  
  float voltage2 = 5*inputVoltage2/1024; 
  Serial.println(voltage2); 
}
```

MATLAB code:

```
delete(instrfind({'Port'},{'COM7'}));

s = serial('COM7', 'BaudRate', 9600);

fopen(s);

a=fgetl(s);

disp(a)

fclose(s);
```

However, the value received has a weird symbol in front of it as shown below:

[image]

Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... post the text instead

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your "weird" symbol, but the arduino code

```
 float voltage2 = 5*inputVoltage2/1024;
```

is integer math.  You should user floating point ,
as ::

```
 float voltage2 = 5.0*inputVoltage2/1024.0;
```

And to determine what is your character, do a "dec2hex" or a "mat2str" on the string.
It will show the hex value
.

```
dec2hex(a)
```

The first item on the matrix will be your character.